# List all versions of a library using bash

Tags: 12.04, bash

I wrote this script to get the version number of all the libpcap libraries on my Ubuntu system.

```
#!/bin/bash

allLIBs=$(ldconfig -p | grep libpcap)
echo "$allLIBs" | while IFS= read -r a; do
    loc=$(echo $a | awk '{print $4}')

    # resolve if a sym link
    if [[ -h $loc ]]; then
        loc_res=$(readlink -f $loc)
    fi

    # get lib name
    libName=$(basename $loc_res)

    echo "$loc"
    echo "    resolved to: $loc_res"
    echo "    lib name: $libName"
done
```

The output of this script on my machine is

```
/usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1
    resolved to: /usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1.8.0-PRE-GIT
    lib name: libpcap.so.1.8.0-PRE-GIT
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.0.8
    resolved to: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.1.5.3
    lib name: libpcap.so.1.5.3
/usr/local/lib/libpcap.so
    resolved to: /usr/local/lib/libpcap.so.1.8.0-PRE-GIT
    lib name: libpcap.so.1.8.0-PRE-GIT
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so
    resolved to: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.1.5.3
    lib name: libpcap.so.1.5.3
```

1. How can I get the number after the so?
2. Is this the correct way to get the version number of all libpcap libraries installed on my machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are unsure about the number of versions of the library installed:

```
echo "$(ldconfig -p | grep -Eo '/[^ ]+libpcap[^ ]+$')" | \
        while IFS= read -r lib; do readlink "$lib"; done
```

If you do not have any white-spaces in the path to the file using just `xargs` would suffice:

```
echo "$(ldconfig -p | grep -Eo '/[^ ]+libpcap[^ ]+$')" | xargs -L 1 readlink
```

If there is only one version:

```
readlink "$(ldconfig -p | grep -Eo '/[^ ]+libpcap[^ ]+$')"
```

---

To get the version number after `so.`, use `grep`:

```
% grep -Eo '[0-9][^[:alpha:]]+$' <<<'libpcap.so.1.5.3'
1.5.3
```

here we are getting the starting number of the version and then continuing till the end ensuring there is no intermediate alphabetic characters in between.

Comment: Thanks! what does the regular exp do in grep? Using the same regular expression in my script does not work:  allLIBs=$(ldconfig -p | grep -Eo '/[^ ]+"$1"[^ ]+$')

Comment: @ManiAm This does not work inside the script because variable `$1` won't be expanded inside a single quote, you need `allLIBs="$(ldconfig -p | grep -Eo "/[^ ]+"$1"[^ ]+$")"` , better use an array `allLIBs=( "$(ldconfig -p | grep -Eo "/[^ ]+"$1"[^ ]+$" )` and then use `${allLlB[@]}` to get all elements of the array....also i have shown the right way to do it..you don't need that long script for the job..